# matrix - mirror lower triangle to upper triangle

Tags: r, matrix

How to flip the lower.tri with diag and no last row over to upper.tri?

```
m <- structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NA, 66, 77, 88, 99, NA, NA, 333, 444, 
555, NA, NA, NA, 101, 202, NA, NA, NA, NA, 99999), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(c("v_2", "v_3", "v_3a", "v_3b", "v_4"), 
    c("v_0", "v_2", "v_3", "v_3a", "v_3b")))
```

looks like:

```
     v_0 v_2 v_3 v_3a  v_3b
v_2    1  NA  NA   NA    NA
v_3    2  66  NA   NA    NA
v_3a   3  77 333   NA    NA
v_3b   4  88 444  101    NA
v_4    5  99 555  202 99999
```

desired result:

```
     v_0 v_2 v_3 v_3a  v_3b
v_2    1   1   2    3     4
v_3    2  66  66   77    88
v_3a   3  77 333  333   444
v_3b   4  88 444  101   101
v_4    5  99 555  202 99999
```

pretty sure functions `lower.tri()` and `upper.tri()` could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
tm <- t(m)[,-nrow(m)] # or t(m[-nrow(m),])
m[upper.tri(m)] <- tm[upper.tri(tm, diag = TRUE)]
# > m
#      v_0 v_2 v_3 v_3a  v_3b
# v_2    1   1   2    3     4
# v_3    2  66  66   77    88
# v_3a   3  77 333  333   444
# v_3b   4  88 444  101   101
# v_4    5  99 555  202 99999
```